# Laravel 7 why show status code 302 with post data

Tags: php, laravel

I have using laravel 7 to post my data with **bookcontroller@insertbook**.
And I have found show the status code with 302.
But i have check my web.php and controller they is not error come out.
[the status code show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfeRR.png)

Below show my **web.php** code

```
Route::redirect('/' , 'cn');

Route::get('dashboard', function () {
    return redirect()->route('home' , ['language' => app()->getLocale() ?? 'cn']);
});


Route::group([
    'prefix' => '{language}' ,
    'where' => ['language' => '[a-z]{2}']
], function(){

    
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('auth.login');
    })->name('login');

    Auth::routes();

    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function(){

        Route::get('allbook', [
            'uses' =>'BookController@listBook',
            'as' => 'book_index'
        ]);

        Route::get('dashboard', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

        Route::get('addcategory', 'BookController@categoryPage')->name('addCategory');

        Route::post('addcategory','BookController@addnewCategory');

        Route::get('addbook', 'BookController@addBook')->name('addbook');

        Route::get('profile',function(){
            return view('book.profile');
        });

        Route::get('book/edit/{id}', [
            'uses' =>'BookController@edit',
            'as' => 'book_edit'
        ]);
```

Here is my **BookController@insertBook**

```
        Route::post('addbook','BookController@insertBook');
```

```
        Route::post('book/update/{id}', [
            'uses' =>'BookController@update',
            'as' => 'book_update'
        ]);

        Route::post('book/delete/{id}', [              // this is the directory show in url
            'uses' => 'BookController@delete',          // this is get the BookController @delete method
            'as' => 'book_delete'                      // this is the value you can use "route('book_delete') to run it post"
        ]);

    });

});
```

Below is my **bookcontroller** with **insertbook** function

```
public function insertBook(Request $request)
    {

         $request->validate([
            'title-name' => 'required|min:3|max:100',
            'author-name' => 'required|regex:/^[\pL\s\-]+$/u',
            'description' => 'required|min:10|max:300',
            'category' => 'required',
            'status' => 'required',
        ]);


        $data = $request->input();

        $books = new Books;

        $books->title = $data['title-name'];
        $books->author = $data['author-name'];
        $books->description = $data['description'];
        $books->category = $data['category'];
        $books->status = $data['status'];
        $books->save();

        $request->session()->flash('message', 'You have successfully added a book!');

        return back();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the laravel docs *https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/redirects* the back() method is a http redirect method. The http response code 302 is the default behaviour for this helper method as you can see in your vendor directory:

vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php

or here in the implementation:

```
if (! function_exists('back')) {
    /**
     * Create a new redirect response to the previous location.
     *
     * @param  int  $status
     * @param  array  $headers
     * @param  mixed  $fallback
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    function back($status = 302, $headers = [], $fallback = false)
    {
        return app('redirect')->back($status, $headers, $fallback);
    }
}
```

If you want to learn more about HTTP Response Codes:

You might find this link helpful:

*https://umbraco.com/knowledge-base/http-status-codes/*

Answer (score 1):

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 302 Found redirect status response code indicates that the resource requested has been temporarily moved to the URL given by the Location header

It is true to return the `302` status code because you are returning the `back()` method which redirects to the previous destination.

Comment: So is it not big issue for keep using the back() right?